# Given the Riemann mapping $\ f_t(z):\mathbb{D} \to B_t$ with $f_t(0)=0,f_t'(0)>0$, prove that $f_t'(0)$ increases

Tags: complex-analysis

**The exercise**:

For all $t∈(0,+∞)$, given the Riemann mapping $f_t:\mathbb{D}\to B_t$, where $B_t=\{z∈\mathbb{C}:\ |\mathcal{R}(z)|<t,\ |\mathcal{I}(z)| < 1\}$. If $\ f_t(0)=0,\ f_t'(0)>0$ and we take the function:

$$\begin{align}
α:\ & (0,+∞) \longrightarrow (0,+∞)\\
& \qquad \quad t  \mapsto f_t'(0)
\end{align}$$

Prove that:

1. $α$ is an increasing function
2. $\lim_{t \to ∞} α(t) = \frac{4}{π}$
3. $\lim_{t \to 0} \frac{α(t)}{t} = \frac{4}{π}$
4. $α$ is continuous

---

**What I've tried**:

Since $\{f_t\}_t$ is a normal family, it is uniformly bounded over compacts (don't use this anymore). After that I've tried the following using the Cauchy integral formula:

$$|α'| = |f_t''(0)| ≤ \frac{1}{π} \int_{\mathbb{D}_{3/4}} \frac{|f_t(z)|}{|z|^3}dz ≤ \frac{8}{π} \max\{1,+\sqrt{1+t^2}\} \int_{\mathbb{D}_{3/4}}dz = 12 ·\max\{1,+\sqrt{1+t^2}\} $$

but that only gives me that the modulus is bounded, and I wan't $α'>0$.

For 2, 3 and 4 I have no idea of what to do.

Any help?

Comment: You cant have 2. and 3. both holding.

Comment: @zhw sorry, I wrote it wrong. In 3. $t \to 0$, I've just edited it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(2)$ Let $S=\{z\in\mathbb{C}:|\Im (z)| < 1\}$ and $$\varphi (z)=\frac{e^{\frac{\pi}{2}z}-1}{e^{\frac{\pi}{2}z}+1}.$$ Of course $\varphi $ is a bijective mapping of $S \to \mathbb{D}$. We consider $$g_t(z)=\varphi \circ f_t(z)$$ and $\Omega_t=g_t(\mathbb{D})$.
Since 
$$\min_{|z|=1} |g_t(z)|=\min_{z\in \partial S}|\varphi (z)|=\frac{e^{\frac{\pi}{2}t}-1}{e^{\frac{\pi}{2}t}+1}\to 1\quad (t\to \infty),$$
$\{\Omega_t\}$ is a sequence of simply connected domains with $0\in \Omega_t ⊂\mathbb{D}$. Having :
$\quad\bullet \quad \operatorname{dist}\,(0, \partial\Omega_t)\to 1\quad$  as $t\to \infty$
$\quad\bullet \quad g_t \in \mathcal{H}(\mathbb{D}),\; |g_t(z)|<1$
$\quad\bullet \quad g_t : \mathbb{D}\to \Omega_t \;\;\text{bijective}$
$\quad\bullet \quad g_t(0)=0, \;{g_t}^\prime (0)>0$.

Therefore we see that ${g_t}^\prime (0)\to 1 $ as $ t\to \infty$, which yields $$
\lim_{t\to \infty}\frac{\pi}{\,4\,}{f_t}^\prime(0)=1.$$
$(3)$ Let $$F_t(z)=\frac{\,i\,}{t}f_t(-iz),$$ then $F_t(0)=0,\, {F_t}^\prime(0)=\frac{{f_t}^\prime(0)}{t}>0$ and $F_t(\mathbb{D})=B_{1/t}$. 
The fact that $$
\frac{\,i\,}{t}f_t(-iz)
$$ maps $\mathbb{D} \to B_{1/t}$ is a crucial point.

So $F_t(z)=f_{1/t}(z)$ and hence we have by the result of $(2)$ that $$
\lim_{t\to 0} \frac{{f_t}^\prime(0)}{t}=\lim_{t\to 0}{F_t}^\prime(0)=\lim_{t\to 0}{f_{1/t}}^\prime(0)=\frac{4}{\pi}.
$$
$(4)$ Outline: 
For $t<t_0$, consider $G_t={f_{t_0}}^{-1}\circ f_t$. Then ${G_t}^\prime(0) \to 1$. Thus we know that $$
\lim_{t<t_0, t\to t_0}{f_t}^\prime(0)={f_{t_0}}^\prime(0).$$
The proof of $ \lim_{t_0<t, t\to t_0}{f_t}^\prime(0)={f_{t_0}}^\prime(0)$ is done similarly.

Answer (score 1):

Hint for 1: For $0<s<t,$ look at $(f_t)^{-1}\circ f_s.$ This is a holomorphic map of $\mathbb D$ into $\mathbb D$ that fixes $0.$ What does the Schwarz Lemma tell you?

Hint for 2: It looks like the maps $f_t$ converge to the unique Riemann mapping $g$ of the disc onto the full strip with $g(0)=0, g'(0)>0.$ So find that $g,$ compute $g'(0).$